# Web GCloud cannot connect and SDK reachability failed and Bash commands not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

My Web Google Cloud Shell instance is always stuck at the state of connecting. Sometimes I try clearing browsing data and then reload but it doesn't help. Even if it works for that time, after a while the problem would emerge again. Because of this I went on to using Google Cloud SDK but then I found 2 problems:

1. Reachability check failed on executing "gcloud init"
2. I could not execute bash commands inside Cloud SDK Shell

I have been using bash commands (like `IFS` and for loop) for executing some commands in Web Cloud Shell now I cannot get them to work on SDK Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please file a feedback report using the button shown in the picture below?  This would allow our team to start investigating what's going on.

[image: Google Cloud Console screenshot]

Comment: I am facing the same problem here! Maybe some kind of infinite loop is loading the initial scripts `.bashrc` `.profile` e.t.c are running recursively.

Comment: But I am pretty sure none of my dot files are doing this. And the problem is in cloudshell!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a specific issue for your Cloud Console, as mentioned in the previous answer, I suggest to file a ticket from your Cloud Console to Support, or file a ticket in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), in order to get support for this issue.